# App Feedback Form

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I am developing an app that will have a feedback form in it.
I am planning to do the form using HTML/CSS will not upload it to the web.

Will it work even if it is not published online?
What i'll be doing is to make a form using HTML/CSS and just call its index.html in the app using UIWebView. But of course the user will need internet connection to send the email.

Or you can give me suggestions on how will I able to do a feedback form in other ways.

Comment: Just present a message composer to your support link and let the user do the rest.  No need to hack the email UI to support your own CSS/HTML

Comment: @CodaFi Yeah i can do that, but how will a able to fill the mail with fields that user will fill out?

Comment: [The documentation, sir](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: Why is a web view sending an email?  You could certainly display a local html file in a UIWebView; there's no issue with that.  I'm not sure what this has to do with email?

Comment: Use Formkit to help you with simple forms.

Answer (score 3):

You can use other 3rd party tools for managing feedback.

Instabug (http://instabug.com) is a good one, it isn't only text feedback but it can also be visual feedback with screenshot that the user can draw on, all done in-app.

It also sends an report with the device, OS, user location, connectivity, etc with each feedback sent.

Above all, it's free!

PS. I work @ Instabug, let me know if you need any help.

Comment: I've read about instabug, and from what I understand, it is activated when the device is shaked. Seems like a nice way to do it, but how do you instruct the user that he/she should shake the device to trigger the feedback? After all, it's not necessarily something the user would know, intuitively.

Comment: Thats true. Out of the box, the SDK shows an alert on the first time that the user opens the app, telling them to "Shake the device to send feedback". However, you can switch this off and have your own way of telling them.

Comment: BTW, you don't necessarily need to use the shake gesture, the SDK offers 3 more gestures; the screenshot (home+lock), the three finger swipe, or a chat-heads-like button (for beta apps). You can also switch them all off and code your own gesture that calls into the SDK

Comment: What are other alternatives to instabug?